# Quotient vs Ratio vs Fraction

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms

I am mathematician for whom English is the second language.
In general I feel like I do not have major problems keeping up with math vocabulary, whether I am reading an article or giving a lecture.
That being said, there is one question which have been bothering me for quite a long time.
I am not exactly clear on the nuances of the meaning the three words from the title.
To be more specific, the essences of my concerns can be articulated as

> *Can I use words "**quotient**", "**ratio**", and "**fraction**" interchangeably?*

I am mostly concerned about using them within math academia environment, although more general rules would also be interesting to see.
In particular, which of the words from the list would be appropriate to use when talking about dividing one function by another one?

Ultimately, even laconic **yes**/**no** answer will be greatly appreciated.
However, I am also somewhat curious to see detailed explanation of how each of these words is different from the others.

**PS** As mentioned in the comment section by @BrianDonovan, my list of three words can probably be extended with the word *"**proportion**"*.

---

**EDIT**:
Following advices of @Rathony, I include the outline of Wikipedia definitions of each of these words:

> - In mathematics, a [ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio) is a relationship between two numbers indicating how many times the first number contains the second
> - A [fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)) (⋯) represents a part of a whole or, more generally, any number of equal parts.
>     (⋯)
>     The word [fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)) is also used to describe mathematical expressions that are not rational numbers, for example algebraic fractions (quotients of algebraic expressions), and expressions that contain irrational numbers (⋯)
> - (⋯) a [quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient) (⋯) is the result of division.

Let me point out once again that I am particularly interested in the differences in use of these words in math academic environment, e.g. about the case when both enumerator and denominator of a fraction are general functions or algebraic expressions of some sort.

Comment: Might *proportion* belong in the list too?

Comment: @BrianDonovan It surely does, thank you! I did not even think of this one =\

Comment: Related question in Mathematics Educators beta, [How to explain the difference between the fraction a / b and the ratio a : b?](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-explain-the-difference-between-the-fraction-a-b-and-the-ratio-a-b/7295#7295). I think this question is on-topic there.

Comment: To be laconic about it:  **No**, you can't use them interchangeably.

Comment: @Rathony: If there really is a "domain-specific" fine distinction between *ratios* and *fractions*, it didn't leap out at me when I followed your link there. But to my mind there's at least one significant "syntactic" difference, in that you can reasonably ask *What **fraction** of the contents of your odd-sock drawer have an ex-partner now relocated to an alternate universe?* Okay - maybe that's not the most "reasonable" question ever asked, but it's well-enough phrased. Which wouldn't be the case if we'd used the word ***ratio***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question doesn't include any research and nobody is pointing it out. Why? Isn't it a "what does it mean" question?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't see any difference between the OP's question and [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295249/what-is-the-difference-mature-responsible-and-sensible).

Comment: @Rathony Thank you for interesting links. In reply your last commentary, I can say following: it seems to me that [the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/295249/134229) you linked compares well-defined words which are not even synonyms, strictly speaking. In contrast with the linked question, I am trying to figure out differences in meanings of words which are almost synonyms, at least within the context of math academia.

Comment: @Rathony My research on the topic is limited by skimming Wikipedia articles on each of the words,  checking [thesaurus.com](thesaurus.com) for synonyms and searching this website. In my opinion there is nothing in these sources that would not be considered a "common knowledge" here, so I decided to post question. If you think that including material from these websites (or from anywhere else) into the original post will benefit the question, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question that I linked in the above comment to FumbleFingers hoping the OP would edit the question. Now, the rule of this community is as follows: You need to specify what you don't understand based on your own research. You didn't provide anything. That's why I pointed out that there is no difference between the two questions. I would advise you to edit your question. (Welcome to EL&U)

Comment: No, no, no. You have to show what you have done. Your question is just this. "Can I use the following words "quotient", "ratio", and "fraction" interchangeably?". That is blatantly off-topic here. What do you not understand based on your research? What bothers you the most? Your question doesn't stand as on-topic.

Comment: @Rathony The very first item in "What topics can I ask about here?" [section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of "asking" article from help center is *"**Word choice and usage**"*. I believe my question perfectly falls into this category.

Comment: @Rathony I was unable to find an explicit rule which says I have to provide results on my own research in each question. I understand that this is a matter of good manners up to certain extent, but I think it is redundant to quote well-known facts or definitions. However, I would definitely edit my post according to your recommendations if you could either provide me with the link to the rule about research, or if you provide convincing argument why the common knowledge is not sufficient in this case.

Comment: I would advise you to read very carefully when taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). The rule that you mentioned is this. ***Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered***. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). You need to see why the linked question was closed and figure it out. It will take too long for me to explain all.

Comment: @Rathony Thank you for reply and for relevant links. I agree that my question can be matched with ***Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase*** category, but I don't think ***Single word requests*** is appropriate section. I believe I provided readers with ***information on how it*** (*the ideal word or phrase*) ***will be used***, as I mention *academic environment*, math *articles*, and *lectures*, even though I couldn't find this rule anywhere. However, I appreciate _a lot_ both your advice about seeing why the other questions were closed, and overall time you spent on me.

Comment: I would advise you to post your question to the site I linked. They are experts in mathematics and you said you are a mathematician. I hope you didn't take it personally. I just wanted to guide you to write a better/more on-topic question. You can always ask on-topic questions related with English Language and its Usage here. Hope to see you again here. Merry Christmas!!!

Comment: @Rathony I appreciate any relevant feedback, especially if it is as helpful and polite as yours. Let me thank you again for the useful information and for advices. I am going to ask my question on math education SE right now. Happy Holidays! =)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better answered on another SO site (math educators)

Comment: @Mitch I am not sure the question would be better answered on another SO. However, even if it was the case, there is still no reason to close it, is there? I thought a question gets closed if it _belongs_ on another website and ***does not*** belong here. However, I do not see why wouldn't my question belong on English Language SO, as it is about nuances of word usage. It follows into "***Word choice and usage***" category without any drawbacks. According to the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), my post is welcome here, even if I choose to post it anywhere else

Comment: @Vlad good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common usage observes distinctions that mathematics does not.  The numeral 2 is a valid quotient, but not a fraction or ratio, although 2/1 and 2:1 are implied mathematically.  Quotients may be in decimal form, which is not a proper fraction or ratio.  Quotient is almost exclusively used in explicitly mathematical contexts.

In normal usage, fractions compare parts to wholes. "A small fraction of Green Party candidates support declaring Jupiter as an enemy planet" compares the in group (Jupiter is an enemy) from the whole (all Green Party candidates).

A ratio is normally used to distinguish between two groups, without requiring that the whole is addressed.  "Ironically, Republicans favor mandatory tea drinking in a 2-to-1 ratio over tea party members" is not addressing the whole of all political party members, but specifically comparing the two groups.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it makes the distinctions between words much clearer for me, particularly within the context of your examples. Does the same logic applies in a classroom when we are talking about dividing functions?

Comment: Yes.  You would talk about the quotient as the result of the division, and the fraction as the pre-computed resulted.  In h() = f()/g(), h() is the quotient, and f()/g() is the fraction.  Ratio is unusual to talk about in that context, unless you're describing change.  For example, "The ratio of f^2() to g() approaches infinity faster than f() to g() for f() > 1", means you don't have to redefine a separate h() and h2() (for when f() is squared).

Answer (score 3):

A **quotient** is the result derived from dividing two numbers. For example, dividing 6 by 3 gives a quotient of 2.

A **ratio** is the quantity of one thing relative to the quantity of another. For example, Georgia Tech's guy-to-girl ratio is 2:1. This means that there are twice as many guys as there are girls at Georgia Tech. Another way to look at this is saying that for every girl at Georgia Tech, there are two guys.

A **fraction** is very similar to ratio but not quite. A fraction is a way to describe a quantity in parts of a whole, a whole, or more than a whole. But it is similar to a ratio since it describes quantities in parts, or relative to another quantity (what constitutes a "whole"). For example, after the pizza is cut up into eight pieces, eating one will remove 1/8 of the pizza. One piece is only one of eight pieces that make up the "whole" pizza.

So I guess the short answer is no, that you cannot use these words interchangeably. They each cater to different scenarios. Perhaps, the closest to being used interchangeably are ratio and fraction.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer! I am also curious whether these words are still not entirely interchangeable when used to describe fraction composed of functions, not just integer numbers?

Comment: Are you talking about 1/f(x)? If not, please provide an example.

Comment: I had in mind a bit more general case, something like *f(x)/g(x)* for arbitrary functions *f* and *g*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let us take a look at the definition of these 3 terms.

**Quotient**

> *noun*
>
> a result obtained by dividing one quantity by another

**Ratio**

> *noun*
>
> the quantitative relation between two amounts showing the number of times one value contains or is contained within the other
>
> *e.g.* the ratio of women's job to men's is 8:1

**Fraction**

> *noun*
>
> a numerical quantity that is not a whole number
>
> *e.g.* 1/2, 0.5

Although they might seem similar mathematically but their definition and expression differ from one another. I believe they cannot be used loosely in place of one another, the context or the meaning of the sentence might differ. For example:

> Can I have the **quotient** of the number of pies sold to cupcakes?
>
> Can I have the **ratio** of the number of pies sold to cupcakes?
>
> Can I have the **fraction** of the number of pies sold to cupcakes?

In this case, I'm sure you can now tell the difference of the three words, and whether they can be used interchangeably with one another.

Comment: Your last examples could be improved by providing answers to each question. What I mean is, if 10 pies and 5 cupcakes were sold, the *quotient* of pies and cupcakes is 2, the *ratio* is 2:1, and the *fraction* is kind of nonsensical in this context, but if you really wanted to force it, you could say 1/2, i.e. half as many cupcakes as pies. The point is, the questions have very different answers, because these three words are not interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To be completely honest I do not think I get the nuances of the differences among words' meanings. I feel like each of three example sentences have slightly different tone to it, but I fail to formally articulate unique characteristics of each of the words in question.

Comment: Also, I am wondering whether the same logic as presented in your example applies in different contexts. For example, if I were to replace words *"pies"* and *"cupcakes"* with functions *f* ( *x* ) and *g* ( *x* ), would the sentences remain intact?

Answer (score 0):

**Ratio** is a relationship between numbers or magnitudes with respect to their relative size. Specifically one number can be multiple of the other, part of it or parts of it (two times, one third part, three fourth parts etc).
Quotient is a **number** that names the ratio between two numbers (quotient equal to 1/3 indicates the ratio of one third part). Quotient (number) has the same ratio to 1 as dividend has to divisor. So proportionaly dividend:divisor=quotient:1.
Proper fraction is a **number** less than 1. The numerator has the same ratio to the denominator as fraction has to 1. For example 2 is two thirds of 3. 2/3 is two thirds of 1.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. It would be great if you could find references to bolster your answer.